# Dynamically created input values are not being posted to Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating some dynamic fields via jQuery in my existing form that user is filling, but after submission of that form I am unable to get those fields in my controller. All other fields are present except those which I am creating dynamically. This is my code for inserting the fields:

```
//load the rosters levels using ajax
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/rosters/load-levels',
        'data': {'id': rosterId, 'name': rosterName},
        'method': 'post',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (data) {

            $('<div class="row" id="show_rosters_field_row" style="margin-top: 20px">'+
                '<div class="col-md-3">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-12">'+
                "<label for='position' class = 'control-label'>Position</label>"+
                "<input type='text' name='position[]' class = 'form-control' required>"+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-3">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-12">'+
                "<label for='jersey' class = 'control-label'>Jersey</label>"+
                "<input type='text' name='jersey[]' class = 'form-control' required>"+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-3">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-12">'+
                "<label for='ros_photo' class = 'control-label'>Photo</label>"+
                "<input type='file' name='ros_photo[]' class = 'form-control'>"+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-3">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-12">'+
                "<label for='levels' class = 'control-label'>Roster Levels</label>"+
                "<select id='"+rosterNameForId+"' class='form-control' name='ros_level[]' required></select>"+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<input type="hidden" value="'+rosterId+'" class="roster_id_js" name="_roster_id[]">'
            ).insertAfter($('#add-rosters-before'))

            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                $("#" + rosterNameForId).append('<option value="'+item.id+'" class="form-control">'+item.name+'</option>');
            })
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
```

**Base Form code before appending any fields via js**

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="dynamics-form-outer">
        <h2 style="text-align: center">Add Student</h2>

        @include('partials.error-messages.success')
        @include('partials.error-messages.error')

        {!! Form::open(['url' => 'students/', 'files' =>true, 'id' => '']) !!}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {!! Form::label('title', 'Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'fn form-control', 'required' => 'true']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {!! Form::label('academic_year', 'Academic Year:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::select('academic_year',
                        ['Freshman' => 'Freshman', 'Sohphomore' => 'Sohphomore',
                         'Junior' => 'Junior', 'Senior' => 'Senior'], 'Please Select'
                        ,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {!! Form::label('title', 'Weight(pounds):', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::selectRange('weight', 80, 220, 80, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::label('title', 'Height in Feet:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                        {!! Form::selectRange('height_feet', 4, 7, 4, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::label('title', 'Height in Inches:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                        {!! Form::selectRange('height_inches', 0, 12, 0, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {!! Form::label('pro_free', 'Pro/Free:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::select('pro_free', ['' => 'Please Select', '0' => 'Free', '1' => 'Pro'],'please select',
                 ['class' => 'fn form-control', 'id'=>'pro_free_', 'onchange' => 'return pro()', 'required' => true]) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {!! Form::label('pro_head_photo', 'Pro Head Photo:', ['class' => 'control-label hide-pro']) !!}
                {!! Form::file('pro_head_photo', ['class' => 'fn form-control hide-pro']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {!! Form::label('pro_cover_photo', 'Pro Cover Photo:', ['class' => 'control-label hide-pro']) !!}
                {!! Form::file('pro_cover_photo', ['class' => 'fn form-control hide-pro']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        {{--show custom fields--}}
        <div class="row" style="margin: 20px 20px 20px 0px">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <b>{{$school->name}} Custom Fields: </b>
                <button style="" type="button" id="add-field" class="btn btn-default">
                    Add Fields?</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="dynamic-fields-row">
            {{--will append the data on button click--}}
        </div>

    </div>{{--container fluid closed--}}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @if($customFields)
            @foreach($customFields as $customField)

                <div class="row" id="" style="">
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input value="{{$customField->custom_label}}" readonly type="text" name="custom-field-name[]" class="form-control col-md-3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" name="custom-field-value[]" class="form-control col-md-3" placeholder="Value">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif

        {{--add rosters to students--}}
        <div class="row" id="add-rosters-before">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 style="text-align: center">Add to Sports</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
                        {!! Form::select('rosters', $rosters, null, ['class' => 'form-control',
                        'id' => 'rosters_id']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="add-rosters-btn">Add Roster?</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 300px; padding: 10px">
            <div class="" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px !important; float: left;">
                {!! Form::submit('Create Student', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
```

Comment: @JeremyHarris yes, it is inside the form.

Comment: What I'm seeing here (dunno if I'm right) is that the dynamic element are being inserted after the form has been submitted. It is inside `success: function (data) { }` of your ajax request. That is simply telling Javascript  what to do after AJAX request was successful.

Comment: ajax requests runs when a button inside the form is clicked other than the submit button. @Michel

Comment: Are you using a native form submit with a `<form>` element and a submit button, or are you using AJAX and doing something like serializing the input fields?

Comment: @JeremyHarris I am using native form submit button, ajax is just for populating a dropdown in the form.

Comment: @Adamnick That means ID and NAME would have been submitted `/load/data` afterward you add dynamic input. then use submit button again to submit for second. if I understand well what you meant by "ajax requests runs when a button inside the form is clicked other than the submit button"

Comment: Seems like it should work. Can you show the base form HTML (before anything gets appended)?

Comment: @JeremyHarris updated my question and added both pieces of code.

Comment: There isn't an element with an id of `add-before` in your HTML....did you mean to use `add-rosters-before`?

Comment: same ids are being used on both sides, `add-rosters-before` so its not an issue. @JeremyHarris

Comment: ....you just edited it to show that.

Comment: this is the original code now @JeremyHarris

Answer (score 1):

looks like it was an issue in the html structure, some tags were not being closed. Correcting that fixed my issue.